# General structure of language packs

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt6

I am currently programming a GUI program with PyQt6. It should be multilingual.

## Problem

How to structure language packs / files the best way?

## Idea

### CSV file

I could create a CSV file for every language. It has two columns; one for unique IDs and one for the content. The program gets the content by knowing the ID for every occurrence of text in the GUI.

| ID | CONTENT |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | Welcome to the new program! |
| 32456 | Homepage |
| 64375 | Contact |
| ... | ... |

```
12345; Welcome to the new program!
32456; Homepage
64375; Contact
```

Comment: Don't try to reinvent the wheel. Qt already provides support for translations using `ts` files, the Qt linguist program and the QTranslator class. See the [documentation](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt6/i18n.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have done that with a sqlite database and use it to put out messages in different languages. I load the last used language texts at the beginning of the programm and them use them as needed. Table structure is textid(integer, primary key), messageId(integer), text(char), language(char)